# BibTeX can't open galphac.bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, miktex

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, currently using MiKTeX in combination with Texmaker.
Im using a layout which I got from my university, but when I try to load my .bib-File via F11, I get the following error-message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) The top-level
auxiliary file: vereinbarung.aux I couldn't open style file
galphac.bst ---line 10 of file vereinbarung.aux : \bibstyle{galphac :
} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style
file---while reading file vereinbarung.aux (There were 2 error
messages)
```

The code which I'm using to create the bibliography is the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{galphac}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}
\bibliography{References}
```

As far as I interpret this, I'm probably missing the "galphac.bst" style-file, although after searching for this error message or the file itself, I couldn't find anything that really helps me.

Comment: well do you have the bst? And if yes, where is it?

Answer (score 3):

The bibtex style is here

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/biblio/bibtex/contrib/geralpha

Note it is marked obsolete so not included in the standard distributions, if you must use it just download from the above link and save it in the same folder as your document.